# How to save Dataframe in pdf file in Julia?

Tags: julia, pdflatex

I was facing difficulty in converting dataframe to pdf file. I tried converting first to latex then to pdf, but the thing is I used latexify package to convert dataframe into latex format, but output of the latexify() function is not correct, as when converted to pdf it gives distorted table. So, can you please help me in this? Here is the sample code

```
using DataFrames
using PrettyTables
using LaTeXStrings
using Latexify
# Create a DataFrame
df = DataFrame(A = [1, 2, 3], B = [4, 5, 6], C = [7, 8, 9])
# Convert the DataFrame to a LaTeX table
latex_table = latexify(df,latex=false)
# Print the LaTeX table
println(latex_table)
# Define the LaTeX document as a string
latex_doc = “”"
\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage{booktabs}
\\begin{document}
$latex_table
\\end{document}
“”"
# Save the LaTeX document to a file
write(“mydoc.tex”, latex_doc)
# Define the name of the LaTeX file
latex_file = “mydoc.tex”
# Run the pdflatex command to generate the PDF file
run(`pdflatex $latex_file`)
```

I tried `Latexify` and `PrettyTables` package, with `latexify()` function I got an output which when saved to PDF file gave distorted table. I cross checked with online latex to pdf converter, I found that `latexify()` output was not correct. With `PrettyTables` package I was trying to create latex output of dataframe but failed to do so.

So, please suggest package, function or flag that I should use to save dataframe to PDF file.

Answer (score 8):

This is how you can output data frame to LaTeX:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(A = [1, 2, 3], B = [4, 5, 6], C = [7, 8, 9])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A      B      C
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      4      7
   2 │     2      5      8
   3 │     3      6      9

julia> show(stdout, MIME("text/latex"), df)
\begin{tabular}{r|ccc}
        & A & B & C\\
        \hline
        & Int64 & Int64 & Int64\\
        \hline
        1 & 1 & 4 & 7 \\
        2 & 2 & 5 & 8 \\
        3 & 3 & 6 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Here, I used `stdout` to output to show the result. But instead of `stdout` you can use any stream to write the table contents to.

If you need some more explanations please comment.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by Bugumil will be a typical approach, in some scenarios it is worth knowing that it is possible to generate a PDF from a `DataFrame` without going through LaTeX. This can be done via one Julia's plotting interfaces. For an example:

```
using Plots
gr()
plt = plot(;legend=nothing,xaxis=false,yaxis=false,xticks=false,yticks=false)

annotate!(0.0,1.0,(PrettyTables.pretty_table(String, df, tf_ascii_rounded),12,:left,:top,:black,:Courier))

savefig("mytable.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an extension to *Bogumił Kamiński*'s answer. So, consider you have created a dataframe say `df`. Now, for saving df to a pdf file you need to first convert it to *latex or markdown format*, and then from that, you save it to a pdf file.

I used the latex method, and below is the sample code. Feel free to ask if you need more clarity.

```
using LaTeXStrings
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(A = [1, 2, 3], B = [4, 5, 6], C = [7, 8, 9])
output = IOBuffer()
show(output, MIME("text/latex"),df)
df_table = String(take!(output))

latex_doc = """
\\documentclass{article}
\\usepackage{geometry}
\\geometry{legalpaper, landscape, margin=0.05in}
\\begin{document}
$df_table
\\end{document}
"""

# Save the LaTeX document to a file
write("mydf.tex", latex_doc)
# Define the name of the LaTeX file
latex_file = "mydf.tex"

# Run the pdflatex command to generate the PDF file
run(`pdflatex $latex_file`)
```